# ForkJoinPool getting blocked with just two workers

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I have some code that is not performance-sensitive and was trying to make stacks easier to follow by using fewer futures. This resulted in some code similar to the following:

```
  val fut = Future {
    val r = Future.traverse(ips) { ip =>
      val httpResponse: Future[HttpResponse] = asyncHttpClient.exec(req)
      httpResponse.andThen {
        case x => logger.info(s"received response here: $x")
      }
      httpResponse.map(r => (ip, r))
    }
    r.andThen { case x => logger.info(s"final result: $x") }
    Await.result(r, 10 seconds)
  }
  fut.andThen { x => logger.info(s"finished $x") }
  logger.info("here nonblocking")
```

As expected internal logging in the http client shows that the response returns immediately, but the callbacks executing `logger.info(s"received response here: $x")` and `logger.info(s"final result: $x")` do not execute until after `Await.result(r, 10 seconds)` times out. Looking at the log output, which includes thread ids, the callbacks are being executed in the same thread (ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3) that is awaiting the result, creating a deadlock. It was my understanding that `ExecutionContext.global` would create extra threads on demand when it ran out of threads. Is this not the case? There appears only to be two threads from the global fork join pool that are producing any output in the logs (1 and 3). Can anyone explain this?

As for fixes, I know perhaps the best way is to separate blocking and nonblocking work into different thread pools, but I was hoping to avoid this extra bookkeeping by using a dynamically sized thread pool. Is there a better solution?

Comment: What is `futureConf` ? and where does `req` come from?

Comment: Changed snippet to fix `futureConf`, which wasn't translated over to this snipped correctly. The source of `req` doesn't matter, it's just some specification for an http request.

Comment: What happens if you remove both `Await.result` and the outer wrapping Future? Does the call succeed? Also, may be an idea to add time to the logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to grow the pool (temporarily) when threads are blocked, use `concurrent.blocking`.  Here, you've used all the threads, doing i/o and then scheduling more work with map and andThen (the result of which you don't use).

More info: your "final result" is expected to execute after the traverse, so that is normal.

Example for blocking, although there must be a SO Q&A for it:

```
scala> import concurrent._ ; import ExecutionContext.Implicits._

scala> val is = 1 to 100 toList
scala> def db = s"${Thread.currentThread}"
db: String

scala> def f(i: Int) = Future { println(db) ; Thread.sleep(1000L) ; 2 * i }
f: (i: Int)scala.concurrent.Future[Int]

scala> Future.traverse(is)(f _)
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11,5,main]
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3a4b0e5d
[etc, N at a time]
```

versus overly parallel:

```
scala> def f(i: Int) = Future { blocking { println(db) ; Thread.sleep(1000L) ; 2 * i }}
f: (i: Int)scala.concurrent.Future[Int]

scala> Future.traverse(is)(f _)
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main]
res1: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@759d81f3
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19,5,main]

scala> Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-23,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-27,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-21,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-31,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-17,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-49,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-45,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-59,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-43,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-57,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-37,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-51,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-35,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-53,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-63,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-47,5,main]
```